# не меняется профиль через application.propeties?

Tags: spring-boot

Пытаюсь понять, почему не работает смена профилей. 
У меня есть приложение на spring-boot и нужно, чтобы на разных серверах application.properties подменялся необходимым. Сейчас все запускаю на отдельном сервере томкат(не самим спрингбутом)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мои профили, в application.properties лежит следующее:

```
spring.profiles.active=qa
```

Соответственно, в самом файле qa-application.properties есть к примеру свойство с адресом порта:

```
server.port=8083
```

Правильно ли понимаю, что проблема в том, что мой томкат-контейнер, в который закидываю war-файл - стартует на 8080 порту?

Comment: Думаю, проблема в том, что томкат использоует свои конфиги где указаны порты

Comment: да, дело было в этом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вообще удалить application.properties, а сами профили активизировать передав параметром VM, например так.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

dev- это имя берется из имени файла, например для application-dev.properties  это dev, для application-qa.properties - это qa и т.д.